# constantly monitor a process and display CPU usage

Tags: command-line, cpu-load

I'm running a resource intensive python application but would like to know the CPU usage of this application constantly every 5 seconds and dispay the results.

I use `mpstat -P ALL` but I need to rerun this command every 5 seconds.

Is there a way to poll and display the results constantly every 5 seconds. I would like to format the output as well.

Comment: `watch -n 5 mpstat -P ALL` from a terminal window.

Comment: what about `top` or `htop`?

Answer (score 1):

As others already mentioned, `watch` is the way to go to watch how a command's output changes. However if you want to modify the output and/or use it e.g. in a script, I'd use a loop and `printf`:

```bsh
while :; do
  printf "%s %.1f %s\r" "I need" "$(mpstat -P ALL | awk 'NR==4{print $3}')" "here."
  sleep 5
done
```

This will print "I need *X* here.", wait **`5`** seconds and repeat *overwriting* the existing line of text.
*X* in this example is the value in row **`4`**, column **`3`** of `mpstat`'s output, formatted by as a **`f`**loat rounded to **`1`** decimal. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to break the loop.